# How can I replace for loop of list in to dataframe column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, types

I have dataframe `df_paths` and I want to create column path_pair from the list in column path. Output chooses to look like this table below:

| session_id | path | path_pair |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T01 | [Start, play_series, Null] | [[Start, play_series],[ play_series, Null]] |
| T02 | [Start, play_tv, purchase, Conversion] | [[Start, play_tv],[play_tv,purchase],[purchase, Conversion]] |

My script:

```
for index, row in df_paths.iterrows():
  list_pair = []
  print(index, row['path'])

  for i, val in enumerate(row['path']):
    if i != len(row['path'])-1:
      row_ls = [row['path'][i], row['path'][i+1]]
      # append row list to ls
      list_pair.append(row_ls)
  print(list_pair)

  row['path_pair'] = np.array(row['path'])
  list_new = np.array(list_pair)

  df_paths.at[index, 'path_pair'] = row['path_pair'][list_new] 
  print(df_paths.loc[index]['path_pair'])
```

Error:
`IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`

Comment: Can you share few example of the paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = [['T01', ['Start', 'play_series', 'Null']], [
    'T02', ['Start', 'play_tv', 'purchase', 'Conversion']]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['session_id', 'path'])
df['path_pair'] = df['path'].apply(lambda x: list(zip(x, x[1:])))
df
```

[image]